# How to access and modify pointer type variable declared inside a structure through a element of array containing pointers to the structure?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I declared a double pointer of the structure type and allocated it the required memory using calloc. Then I allocated data member (pointer) required space but it gave segmentation fault error. So only done1 gets printed. Can't we access data member pointers in structure like this?

I even replaced `q[0]` with `*q` but it didn't work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct one
{
    int *a;
};

int main()
{
    struct one **q;
    q = (struct one**) calloc(sizeof(struct one*),10);
    printf("done1\n");
    q[0]->a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("done2\n");
    *(q[0]->a) = 10;
    printf("done3 , q[0]->a stores %d value\n",*(q[0]->a));
    return 0;
}
```

Expected result would be printing of all the "done"'s but only first done is being printed.

Comment: Please compile my code in c++ compiler

Comment: Note that `one **` is a list of pointers. By allocating a "list of pointers", you are not allocating space for actual structs. Either use `one *q = (one*)calloc(sizeof *q, 10);`, or allocate the list, **then** the structs, and **then** the stuff pointed by these structs (as @John also wrote below).

Comment: Expanding on Groo's comment, you're missing a step.  After allocating `q`, you need to allocate each `q[i]` - `for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) q[i] = malloc( sizeof *q[i] );`.  *Then* you can allocate `q[0]->a`.

Comment: Thank you @JohnBode

Comment: Don't cast the value returned from `malloc()` / `calloc()` / `realloc()` in C.

Comment: C is not C++. If the question is about C, add the keyword `struct` to each bare instance of `one` in the code. If the question is about C++, tag it appropriately and you probably shouldn't be using `malloc()` etc. but `new` or whatever is the current best practice there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a `calloc` so that you can create an array of pointers, i.e. `{q[0], q[1], .., q[9]}`. But, each individual element itself is a pointer and since you are doing `calloc`, they are probably initialized to `NULL`. But, then you are directly trying to access `q[0]->a` when `q[0]` is still pointer to `NULL`.

If you attach a debugger and see where it crashes, it will probably be the line `q[0]->a = ...`

First, you have to allocate memory to `q[0]` and then access `q[0]->a`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct one
{
    int *a;
};

int main()
{
    struct one **q;
    q = (struct one**) calloc(sizeof(struct one*), 10);
    printf("done1\n");
    q[0] = (struct one*) calloc(sizeof(struct one), 1);
    q[0]->a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("done2\n");
    *(q[0]->a) = 10;
    printf("done3 , q[0]->a stores %d value\n", *(q[0]->a));
    return 0;
}
```

BTW, your code wasn't compiling on my compiler saying `unknown type one**`. So I changed it with `struct one` everywhere.